# Tkinter cant find Entry variable in a specific frame

Tags: python, tkinter, currency, converters

I wanted to create a GUI application using Python - Tkinter library that converts currencies. For example converts 7 euros to dollars. It should contain different pages and different pages should do only 1 type of conversion. For example, in one page it should convert usd to hkd on the other page it should convert USD to GBP.

I created different frames and the user can navigate between different pages but USD to GBP conversion doesn't work.

Specifically, the convert button should call a function, that function should get the Entry value, convert it to GBP, then change the label value but it fails to read the Entry input. The error i get is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baris\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-6-3f18c68a909a>", line 4, in usd_to_gbp_conversion
    new_gbp_value = c.convert('USD', 'GBP', int(self.entry_usd_to_gbp.get()) )
AttributeError: 'GBP_Page' object has no attribute 'entry_usd_to_gbp'
```

This is all of the code i worked on.

```
    from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
    import tkinter as tk 
    from tkinter import ttk
    LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35) 
    c = CurrencyRates()
    
    
    
    class tkinterApp(tk.Tk): 
          
        # __init__ function for class tkinterApp  
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
              
            # __init__ function for class Tk 
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
              
                
            self.title("Exchange OzU")
            self.geometry("1200x600")
            # creating a container 
            container = tk.Frame(self)   
            container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)  
       
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
       
            # initializing frames to an empty array 
            self.frames = {}   
       
            # iterating through a tuple consisting 
            # of the different page layouts 
            for F in (Start_Page, GBP_Page, EUR_Page, TRY_Page, HKD_Page): 
       
                frame = F(container, self) 
       
                # initializing frame of that object from 
                # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with  
                self.frames[F] = frame  
       
                frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew") 
       
            self.show_frame(Start_Page) 
       
        # to display the current frame passed as 
        # parameter 
        def show_frame(self, cont): 
            frame = self.frames[cont] 
            frame.tkraise()
    
    # first window frame START_PAGE
    class Start_Page(tk.Frame): 
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
              
            # label of frame Layout 2 
            label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Start Page", font = LARGEFONT) 
              
            # putting the grid in its place
            label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)  
       
            # Putting Buttons in place
        
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="USD to GBP", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(GBP_Page)) 
            button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
       
            button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="USD to EUR", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(EUR_Page)) 
            button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
            
            button3 = ttk.Button(self, text ="USD to TRY", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(TRY_Page)) 
            button3.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
            
            button4 = ttk.Button(self, text ="USD to HKD", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(HKD_Page)) 
            button4.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    
    
    # second window frame page1  
    class GBP_Page(tk.Frame):
        def usd_to_gbp_conversion(self):
            new_gbp_value = c.convert('USD', 'GBP', int(self.entry_usd_to_gbp.get()) )
            new_gbp_value = str(new_gbp_value) + " Great Britain Pound"
            new_gbp_label.config(text = new_gbp_value)
          
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):    
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
            label = ttk.Label(self, text ="USD to GBP Page", font = LARGEFONT) 
            label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
       
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Start Page", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Start_Page)) 
            button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
            
            
            entry_usd_to_gbp = ttk.Entry(self,width=20)
            entry_usd_to_gbp.grid(row = 1, column = 5, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
            entry_usd_to_gbp.insert(0,"Enter a USD value: ")
            
            new_gbp_label = ttk.Label(self, text ="... Great Britain Pound") 
            new_gbp_label.grid(row = 1, column = 9, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
            
            convert_button = ttk.Button(self, text ="Convert", command = self.usd_to_gbp_conversion ) 
            convert_button.grid(row = 3, column = 7, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    # second window frame page1  
    class EUR_Page(tk.Frame): 
          
        def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
              
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
            label = ttk.Label(self, text ="USD to EUR Page", font = LARGEFONT) 
            label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
       
            button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Start Page", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Start_Page)) 
            button2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    # second window frame page1  
    class TRY_Page(tk.Frame): 
          
        def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
              
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
            label = ttk.Label(self, text ="USD to TRY Page", font = LARGEFONT) 
            label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
    
            button3 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Start Page", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Start_Page)) 
            button3.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    # second window frame page1  
    class HKD_Page(tk.Frame): 
          
        def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
              
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
            label = ttk.Label(self, text ="USD to HKD Page", font = LARGEFONT) 
            label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
       
            button4 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Start Page", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Start_Page)) 
            button4.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
    
    
    # Driver Code 
    app = tkinterApp() 
    app.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `entry_usd_to_gbp` and `self.entry_usd_to_gbp`?

Comment: If i add self to the variable it adds the variable to the class instance, if not then this variable would be local and it wouldnt be accessible globally. I am new to TKinter but based on OOP principles i think the difference is like this. Do you think the problem is regarding this ?

Comment: without using `self` the variable is available only within the scope that it was created. In this case it is available in the `__init__` method. But once that method terminates, the variable is gone. Using `self` creates an instance variable on the object that will be available as long as the object is.

Comment: @BenjaminHoving thanks for the clarification but my question still stands. How do i access some Entry in an init method ? I am very new to TKinter, maybe i didnt pass the self variable correctly as a parameter in the command parameter ? Im all ears

Comment: I need an answer for this ASAP please can someone help ?